# IIS 7.5 + Classic ASP + Forms Auth = memory leak?

Tags: iis, performance, iis-7.5, asp-classic

When I implement the section titled "TAKING ADVANTAGE OF THE INTEGRATED PIPELINE" from the document below, memory usage counters for the w3wp.exe process increases with request to the classic asp test page.  I am looking at Commit, Working Set, Shareable, and Private Bytes in Resource Monitor. My test page (below) refreshes itself approx. once per second.  Memory usage increases with each request.  The problem does not occur when I remove the modules section from the web.config (below).

Is this by design? Or are there additional configuration changes that I should make to stabilize memory consumption?

My goal to implement forms authentication together with classic asp.  It works great, except this memory issue.

This is a migration of a legacy app to .net, please don't recommend basic authentication or dropping the classic asp requirement.  I also asked this question [here](http://forums.iis.net/t/1198079.aspx/1?IIS%207%205%20Classic%20ASP%20Forms%20Auth%20Memory%20leak%20).

Thanks!

**The document:**

http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/building-and-running-aspnet-applications/how-to-take-advantage-of-the-iis-integrated-pipeline

**My Server/IIS config:**

Win2k8 R2 SP 1, 64 Bit,  IIS 7.5, 7.5 GB Memory
Fresh EC2 server: Windows_Server-2008-R2_SP1-English-64Bit-SQL_2008_R2_SP2_Express-2013.04.14 (ami-c082e3a9) m1.large
Integrated app pool, .NET v4.0, Integrated, uses app pool identity, memory limits set to 0 (no limit), 64 bit only

**Web.config:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
<modules  runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
<remove name="UrlAuthorization" />
<remove name="DefaultAuthentication" />
<remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
<add name="FormsAuthentication" type="System.Web.Security.FormsAuthenticationModule" preCondition="" />
<add name="DefaultAuthentication" type="System.Web.Security.DefaultAuthenticationModule" preCondition="" />
<add name="UrlAuthorization" type="System.Web.Security.UrlAuthorizationModule" preCondition="" />
</modules>
</system.webServer>
<system.web>
<sessionState mode="Off" />
<compilation debug="false" />
</system.web>
</configuration>
```

**Test page:**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>test</title>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1">
</head>
<body><%=Now()%></body>
</html>
```

Edit: Windows update is current.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I believe that I have answered my own question here.**

I tracked down the author of the article and found that he has since founded a company that offers a windows monitoring/profiling service called LeanSentry (I am not affiliated with the service in any way.)

I connected the service to my test EC2 server and found that each request to my test page was causing a 404 error due to a **missing favicon.ico static file**, and the authentication module was consuming memory in the process.  I placed the missing favicon file in the root website folder and the memory usage now remains flat after an initial growth period of maybe 10 minutes.

**I hope this is helpful if you are facing the same problem!**